# help setting up coldfusion 9 with IIS7

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5

I downloaded ColdFusion 9 and set it up, at the end it asks to go to the Administration, but when it does I get an HTTP 404 error.

Also while trying to run cfm files in dreamweaver I get the same error. I can however browse the testing server and see all of the files on it. Any ideas?

I primary work with ASP.NET on my local machine if that matters.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? What version of IIS? Are you trying to browse to `http://localhost/cfide/administrator/index.cfm`?

Comment: Did you add the mapping for .cfm and .cfc into IIS?

Comment: @Ciaran Archer I'm using Windows 7 64bit, IIS 7.5.

Comment: @jcreamer898 I did not add any mappings to IIS, regardless, if I try to run an .htm file it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion 9 doesn't support IIS 7 without first installing the 9.0.1 update. This may be your problem. You can go [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads_updates.html#cf9) to download and install it. [This](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/whatsnew_cf901.html) link also provides some good info of what is new in the update. Even if this isn't your problem, you probably should still install it as it is a fairly big update.

Comment: I downloaded the update but the update wants me to choose the CFIDE directory, my coldfusion9 folder doesn't contain anything even close to "CFIDE" anywhere. Ugh this shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: It looks like I have a different than you so I'm kinda guessing but it seems like there is a wwwroot folder inside the coldfusion9 folder. It might be in there. Sorry I don't have something more definite for you. The CFIDE folder is there somewhere so just do some searching and I'm sure you'll find it. When you installed ColdFusion, what kind of setup did you choose? Server? Multi-Server? J2EE?